# Is there a function to sort an array by number if each number is assigned to a name

Tags: python

I am creating a program where there is an array within. Is there a way to sort it despite it being zipped. The list features a name assigned to an accuracy, depending on if they counted correctly

I have tried using sorted.

```
if not name in people:
    people.append(name)
    pos1=people.index(name)
    if accuracy3 == "Yes":
        bagsByPerson.append(1)
        secondaryAccuracy.append(1)
        accuracy4=secondaryAccuracy[pos1]/bagsByPerson[pos1]
        accuracy5.append(accuracy4)

    else:
        bagsByPerson.append(1)
        secondaryAccuracy.append(0)
        accuracy4=secondaryAccuracy[pos1]/bagsByPerson[pos1]
        accuracy5.append(accuracy4)

print(accuracy3)
zipped=zip(people,accuracy5,bagsByPerson)
sorting= set(zipped)
sorted(sorting, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(sorting)
```

I want a list to be created looking like: `{('Justin', 1.0, 1), ('Xiao', 0.5, 2)}`

But it looks like: `{('Xiao', 0.5, 2), ('Justin', 1.0, 1)}`

Comment: What's `people`

Comment: Just to add on: the accuracy is the float, the integer is the total number counted

Comment: `sorted` returns a list so you have to assign it to the variable

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by defaults abides by an ascending order (i.e. small first). To reverse that order, just add `reversed=True` to `sorted(...)`:

```
sorting = sorted(sorting, key=lambda x: x[1], reversed=True)
```

Also don't forget to reassign to a variable! `sorted` won't change an array in place, it will instead give you a new array with the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using lambda function:

```
sorted_list = sorted(sorting, reversed=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Also, `sorted` returns a list so you have to assign it to the variable and then print it